# Nativescript + Angular 2 chatService

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

i have a trouble.
here i let my code.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b651408a8419f13a949d719e6b87d8ea

in my app i connect to the firebase cloud message service, in the appComponent i listen the messages that firebise send and emit the data content whit the DataInterchage.service, in the chatComponent i suscribe to the event emited and i process the data.

the problem is the next. when I receved the data, i set the this.messeges variable the data content but the view dont update.

what do you believe that be?

Comment: are you using a list view?

Comment: Yes, it is in the link that I passed, it is in the file Chat.Component.html

Comment: you need to manually call the list view refresh function

Comment: the listview is not the problem. The problem is that the variable changed his value but not update the view.
Ej: this.messeges = "hola" in view // hola.
this.messeges = data // data = "hola mundo", in view // hola.
the variable changed his value but the data binding not work

Comment: `the listview is not the problem`, `not update the view`. Yeah, if the data is updating but the view isnt, its a list view problem. Ive had this problem before

Answer (score 0):

when you set `this.messages` your code might be running outside the angular because that code is written in service callback. that is why when you assign values to variable it doesn't update the view.

try running code inside the angular NgZone. after that your view will be updated successfully.

for your code snippet will be

```
import {NgZone,ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";
export class ChatComponent  implements OnInit{

constructor(
    private zone: NgZone,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.user = JSON.parse(appStorage.getString("user_info"));
    this.me = {
        id: this.user.id,
        name: this.user.full_name,
        pictureUrl: this.user.icon
    };
    this.other = {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        pictureUrl: "",
        coverUrl: ""
    };

    this.emitter.msgRecived$
        .subscribe(data => {
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            this.http.get(`${ env['api_route'] }/api/users/${ data.user }`)
                .subscribe((res: Response) => {
                    let user = res.json().data;

                    this.other = {
                        id: user.id,
                        name: user.full_name,
                        pictureUrl: user.icon,
                    };
                    this.zone.run(()=>{
                        this.messages.push({
                            sender: this.other,
                            content: data.message,
                            date: data.date
                        });
                    });

                    console.dump(this.other);
                    console.dump(this.messages)

                }, (err: Response) => {
                    this.oauth.isLogged(err);
                });
        });
    }
}
```